# Bound on distance when values are multiplied by bounded non negative function

Tags: inequality

Suppose $0 \leq m \leq f(x) \leq M $, is it possible to construct an upper bound on $| f(x) x - f(y) y |$  of the form
$$| f(x) x - f(y) y | \leq c | x - y | $$
for some constant $c$ that depends on $m$ and $M$?

Comment: Nope, not at all. The condition says that $xf(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is a stronger form of continuity. This would imply $f$ is continuous where $x \neq 0$. But, not every bounded function is continuous, or indeed, continuous anywhere!